# How to edit reference model data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model, and a user_details model. User_details just contains more details about a user.

I'm trying to create a page where someone can edit a user and user_details for that user all on one page, but since i have 1 row in my users table, and no rows in my user_details table, no text fields show up on my edit page.

How can i get the text fields for the user_details to show up on my edit page if no data exists in the user_details table?

Part of my contacts_controller:

```
# GET /contacts/1/edit
    # shows a users profile in edit mode
    def edit
        @userProfile = User.find(params[:id])
        @userProfile.build_user_details
        #@userProfile.user_details.build
        #question.answers.build
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
        end
    end

    # POST /contacts/1/edit
    # actually updates the users data
    def update_user

        @userProfile = User.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|

            if @userProfile.update_attributes(params[:user])

                format.html {
                    flash[:success] = "Information updated successfully"
                    render :edit
                }
            else 

                format.html {
                    flash[:error] = resource.errors.full_messages

                    render :edit
                }
            end
        end
    end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]

  # Virtual attribute for authenticating by either username or email
  # This is in addition to a real persisted field like 'username'
  attr_accessor :login

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :login, :first_name, :last_name, :home_phone, :cell_phone, :work_phone, :birthday, :home_address, :work_address, :position, :company, :user_details

  has_one :user_details, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_details

  # validates email or username when logging in
  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

end
```

User_details model

```
class UserDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

edit.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for(@userProfile, :url => {:controller => "my_devise/contacts", :action => "update_user"}, :html => {:class => "form grid_6"}, :method => :post ) do |f| %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Update profile information</legend>


            <%= f.label :first_name, "First Name" %>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, :required => "required" %>

            <%= f.label :last_name, "Last Name" %>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, :required => "required" %>

            <%= f.label :username, "Username" %>
            <%= f.text_field :username, :required => "required" %>

            <% f.fields_for :user_details do |d| %>

                    <%= d.label :home_phone, "Home Phone" %>
                <%= d.text_field :home_phone %>

                <%= d.label :cell_phone, "Cell Phone" %>
                <%= d.text_field :cell_phone, :required => "required" %>

                <%= d.label :work_phone, "Work Phone" %>
                <%= d.text_field :work_phone %>

                <%= d.label :birthday, "Birthday" %>
                <%= d.text_field :birthday %>

                <%= f.label :email, "Email" %>
                <%= f.text_field :email, :required => "required" %>

                <%= d.label :home_address, "Home Address" %>
                <%= d.text_field :home_address, :required => "required" %>

                <%= d.label :work_address, "Work Address" %>
                <%= d.text_field :work_address %>

                <%= d.label :position, "Position" %>
                <%= d.text_field :position %>

                <%= d.label :company, "Company" %>
                <%= d.text_field :company, :required => "required" %>

            <% end %>


            <div class="action">
                <%= f.submit "OK", :class => "button button-orange" %>
                <button class="button button-gray" type="reset">Reset</button>
            </div>

        </fieldset>

       <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out that the entire time, I was missing an `=`.

I changed

```
<% f.fields_for :user_details do |d| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :user_details do |d| %>
```

and they are all there.

Comment: I once typed "appliaction_id" instead of "application_id" and it took me 2 days to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You used wrong name of association:

`has_one :user_detail`, not `has_one :user_details,`

`@userProfile.build_user_detail`, not `@userProfile.build_user_details`

When you edit and update action, your http method is `put`, not `post`, so change this:

```
<%= form_for(@userProfile, :url => {:controller => "my_devise/contacts", :action => "update_user"}, :html => {:class => "form grid_6"}, :method => :post ) do |f| %>
```

To this:

```
<%= form_for(@userProfile, :url => {:controller => "contacts", :action => "update_user"}, :html => {:class => "form grid_6"}, :method => :put ) do |f| %>
```

Try edit and update again.

But i prefer rename the `update_user` action to `update`, it will follow the convention of rails, make for your edit & update easier. If your route to edit and update contact like this:

```
edit_contact GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)  contacts#edit
     contact PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)        contacts#update
```

You only need define form:

```
<%= form_for(@userProfile, :html => {:class => "form grid_6"}) do |f| %>
```

I think you also need to add `new` and `create` action to contacts controller, so form will know if user have not `user profile` yet, it will create new instead of update.

Comment: My model is called "user_details.rb" so changing it to 'has_one :user_detail' causes an error.

Comment: so,try my code and except change association name, it's mean use `use `user_details` in `has_one` and `build`